# Remove GTK+ container children, repopulate it, then refresh

Tags: c, gtk, refresh, widget

I'm into a problem with a GTK+ C application. I have a container that, when starting the application, contains a button. During the running an user interation must cause this widget to contain more of them.
I need to write a function that removes all the "old" inner buttons, then adds all the ones from a list and finally refresh the view. This is what I'm writing but some parts are missing (TODOs)

```
void refresh_sequence_panel() 
{
    GSList* iterator = NULL;
    GtkWidget* button;

    // TODO: Here the container must be empty

    // Now add all the buttons
    for (iterator = steps; iterator; iterator = iterator->next) {
       button = gtk_button_new_from_stock(GTK_STOCK_ADD);
       gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, SEQ_BUTTON_W, SEQ_BUTTON_H);
       gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(sequence_panel), button, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
       handler_id = g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(seq_popup), GTK_BOX(sequence_panel));
    }

    // TODO: Now refresh the view, so I can see the changes...
}
```

Hope that someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Removing all children:

```
GList *children, *iter;

children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(container));
for(iter = children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter))
  gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
g_list_free(children);
```

Note that the above just deletes each child widget directly, rather than asking the container to remove it (with `gtk_container_remove()`), this is [recommended by the documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove) and matches what you intend, so it's fine in my opinion.

There's no point in "refreshing the view", as long as you actually add and show the newly built widgets to the container. GTK+ is event-based, and adding children to a container makes the container realize it needs to refresh its visual appearance automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure it need a refresh.

Comment: You can also do:

    gtk_container_foreach (GTK_CONTAINER (container), (GtkCallback) gtk_widget_destroy, NULL)

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

```c
gtk_container_foreach (GTK_CONTAINER (container), (void*) gtk_widget_destroy, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method that I followed. Because I am using gtkmm on c++

```
Gtk::Box_Helpers::BoxList *childList = &vboxImgLst->children();
Box_Helpers::BoxList::iterator start = childList->begin();
Box_Helpers::BoxList::iterator end = childList->end();

childList->erase(start, end);
```

where **vboxImgLst** is,

```
VBox *vboxImgLst;
```

Hope this will help to someone who are using gtkmm and c++.

Thanks

Comment: Thankfully this ugly additional API was removed in `gtkmm` 3, as it seems very unintuitive, at least from the PoV of `Container.get_children()`, which (necessarily) returns non-owning pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me (it's a variation of unwind's answer):

```
Glib::ListHandle<Widget*> childList = this->get_children();
Glib::ListHandle<Widget*>::iterator it = childList.begin();

while (it != childList.end()) {
    remove(*(*it));
    it++;
}
```

(GTKMM 2.4)

Comment: There is a major caveat for `Gtk::manage()`d widgets: `Container.remove()` on those does *not* destroy the widget, assuming it's a typical one that originally had a floating reference from the C lib. Instead, `gtkmm` restores the floating ref. So if you `manage()` a widget & later remove it from its parent, it stays alive with a floating ref. This means that if you expected that removal to `delete`/free the widget as it would in GTK+, you'd be wrong & causing a possibly large memory leak. So, you have to `remove()` and `delete`, but then since `delete` will `remove()`, you should just `delete`